# How to save and restore the result of the command 'set'?

Tags: vimscript, options

From [`:h :set`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Aset) we
know that

> `:se[t]`      Show all options that differ from their default value.

In a vimscript I'd like to save all these options which have been modified by
the user, modify them and later restore them to the value set by the user.

How can I do that easily?

Do I have a way to simply store the result of `:set` (or a similar command) into a variable that I could source or pass to another command later to restore what it contains?

Or do I have to manually parse the output of the command (which I can do but is a lot of work for nothing if a simpler alternative exists)?

Comment: We already know that options start with & symbol. We can give a verbose set command and then record the output in a variable or register and then split each of them and store their values in a dictionary and then restore from that .

Comment: @SibiCoder: Yes I can parse the result manually but that's not really convenient, my question was about finding a more automatic way to do that.

Comment: How about saving vim info files before editing a file and restoring the options through that? Do we have any options from that?

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard way to do that, and doing it without support from Vim would be problematic at best.  However, there is an `:option` command and an `OptionSet` autocommand event, so there might be enough interest for a "save / restore state" feature.  Ask on `vim_dev`.

Comment: there usually is no need to save/restore all options. Usually one wants to save/restore only a couple of them. In that case, doing it manually using `:let ... = &option` is the way to go. Note, you might want to explicitly check for buflocal/winlocal/global local options.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Damn I didn't know the `:option` command it is pretty cool! You're right maybe I'll hit vim_dev. @ Christian: Yes I get that this isn't a commom workflow, actually I'm juste trying to implement an idea of mine but maybe that's not such a good one :-)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Being able to find which options (global and local) differ from defaults would be useful.  Currently (1) there is no way to make Vim spill out a complete list of options (i.e. taking into account compilation models etc.), and (2) it isn't even documented which options have local versions (F.i. does `selection` have a local version? One has to read the sources to find out.)

Comment: @SatoKatsura you mean apart from `:set all` (which does not list terminal options)? 2) It is documented at each option value `:h 'selection'` tells you, it is a global option. Third, according to the help `:set` returns all options that differ from the default. I don't see what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm trying to actually get a list of available options.  `:set all` produces a table, not a list.  It's probably possible to parse that table with 99% accuracy, given enough motivation.  The `\ ` escapes can account for the remaining 1%. I don't want to go there.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Additionally, I'd also be able to tell (in my humble script) if an option is local or not.  I could experiment with the effect or `setlocal`, for 100+ options.  Again, I don't want to go there.

Comment: @SatoKatsura last time I needed something like this, I [parsed](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn/blob/master/autoload/nrrwrgn.vim#L512-L552) `$VIMRUNTIME/doc/options.txt` (didn't care for terminal options `t_*` however. Addendum: just always assume local option is usually what I do in that case, because that is the one that matters.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Does parsing `options.txt` also tell you if, say, `ballooneval`  is compiled in?

Comment: In your save and restore procedure you simply, you would check `exists(+optionname)`

Comment: That would involve my script having definitive knowledge of what option depends on what feature.  Again, I don't want to go there.  Especially since adding a new function that would return a list of options together with their properties would be mostly trivial.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Tangentially related: it isn't easy to get the actual patchlevel from a script.  `v:version` returns something like 704.  I can also test for `has("patch-7.4.123")`.  But there is no easy way to get `7.4.123`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura indeed. But why would your script need the exact patchlevel? And even then, you wouldn't know, whether the patch n-1 might have been skipped anyhow. So if there is no usuable way using `exists()` I test for the needed minimum patch level, that introduced the patch like `v:version > 704 || v:version == 704 && has("patch148")`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt For error reporting.  Having the actual version in a debug log is nicer than asking the user for a separate output of `vim --version`.  As for patch `n < m` missing, I'm willing to take that chance.  The vast majority of people don't mess with individual patches these days.  Plus, `has("patch148")` is not necessarily better, it doesn't tell you that `patch149` is also present.  So if a feature was added in 148 and fixed in 149, you should in principle check for both values, and adjust.

Comment: @SatoKatsura very true.

Comment: To restore the options default value, you can use `:set {option}&`.

Answer (score 7):

**1. `:mkexrc`**

The easiest way is to use `:mkexrc` command. With this command, we can save all changed options into a file. When you need to restore back all the saved options from the file, just`:source` it.

```
mkexrc snapshot
source snapshot
```

**2. `:set` and `:redir`**

The `:mkexrc` command necessarily uses a file to hold all options.(And it also saves current key mappings.) When we do not want to use any file, we can redirect output of `:set` command into vim variable with `:redir`.

```
redir => snapshot
silent set
redir END
```

Then, we can restore back all the options from snapshot as follows.

```
for opt in split(snapshot,'\n')[1:]
    exe "silent set " . opt
endfor
```

The above approach is quick and easy to use. But the approach has two problems. First, we have to escape some characters including white spaces from the snapshot([`:help option-backslash`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#option-backslash). Otherwise we might meet errors when these characters not being escaped. For instance,

```
set breakat=@ !+=
```

raises the error 'E518' but,

```
set breakat=@\ \!+=
```

works well.

And second problem is that all the special keys are changed to normal characters when we redirect the output to snapshot. For example, `^I`(tab) is literally changed to `^` and `I`. The workaround could be complicated a little bit.

```
let g:optionDict = {}

function SaveOpts()
    redir => snapshot
    " We make a snapshot of options which differ from their default value.
    " If we want to make a snapshot of all options, do set all.
    silent set
    redir END

    for opt in split(snapshot, '\W\+')
        if strlen(opt) > 3
            if exists('&' . opt)
                exe 'let g:optionDict.'. opt . '=&' . opt
            elseif opt[0:1] == 'no' && exists('&' . opt[2:])
                exe 'let g:optionDict.'. opt[2:]. '=&' . opt[2:]
            endif
        endif
    endfor
endfunc

function RestoreOpts()
    for [opt, val] in items(g:optionDict)
        try
            exe 'silent set ' . opt . '=' . escape(val, " \t|\\\"")
        catch /:E474/ " Invalid argument, do set {option} or no{option}
            if val == '1'
                exe 'silent set ' . opt
            elseif val == '0'
                exe 'silent set no' . opt
            endif
        endtry
    endfor
endfunc
```

**3. `:setlocal`**

We can also save an restore option manually with `:setlocal`.

`:setlocal` only affects current buffer or window. If we change options with `:setlocal`, `:setlocal {option}<` or `:set {option}<` can restore back the changed options. The former one sets the local value of {option} from its global value and the latter one remove all the local options so all the option values return to their global values. For instance,

```
setlocal ts=16
set ts<
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access a setting's value using `let option_val = &option` in a script.  What I've seen done is using a dict to store the options that you want to change.  You iterate over the dict to store the old value and set the new.

### Example

This is a more direct approach.  I would use this if the settings are known ahead of time.

```
function! s:do_something() abort
  " Options needed by the plugin
  let plugin_options = {
        \ 'list': 0,
        \ 'winfixwidth': 1,
        \ 'autoindent': 0,
        \ 'filetype': 'ini',
        \ }

  echo 'desired:' plugin_options

  for option in keys(plugin_options)
    execute 'let old_val = &'.option
    execute 'let &'.option.' = plugin_options[option]'
    let plugin_options[option] = old_val
  endfor

  echo 'changed:' plugin_options

  for option in keys(plugin_options)
    execute 'let &'.option.' = plugin_options[option]'
  endfor
endfunction


call s:do_something()
```

The `plugin_options` variable is scoped to the function, so it can be reused to store the old option values.

### Advanced Example

The script below will allow you to change the settings anywhere within your script while maintaining the original settings until you call `s:restore_settings()`

```
function! s:set(option, value) abort
  if !exists('b:_saved_settings')
    let b:_saved_settings = {}
  endif

  " Only save the original values
  if !has_key(b:_saved_settings, a:option)
    execute 'let b:_saved_settings[a:option] = &'.a:option
  endif

  execute 'let &'.a:option.' = a:value'
endfunction

function! s:restore_settings(...) abort
  if !exists('b:_saved_settings')
    return
  endif

  if a:0
    for option in a:000
      if has_key(b:_saved_settings, option)
        execute 'let &'.option.' = b:_saved_settings[option]'
        call remove(b:_saved_settings, option)
      endif
    endfor
  else
    for option in keys(b:_saved_settings)
      execute 'let &'.option.' = b:_saved_settings[option]'
    endfor

    unlet! b:_saved_settings
  endif
endfunction


" Options needed by the plugin
call s:set('list', 0)
call s:set('winfixwidth', 1)
call s:set('autoindent', 0)
call s:set('filetype', 'ini')

echo 'original:' b:_saved_settings
call s:restore_settings('list', 'filetype')
echo 'partial restore:' b:_saved_settings

call s:restore_settings()
```

`s:set()` is somewhat similar to `set`.  It will save the original setting's value if it hasn't been saved yet, then use your setting's value.

Calling `s:restore_settings()` without arguments will do a full restore of your changes.  With arguments, it will partially restore them.  If you decide to use this, it would be worth calling `s:restore_settings()` before initially calling `s:set()` in case your script previously ran into an error before restoration.

Comment: That is not as automatic as I would have expected but that seems to be a good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @statox Yeah, but it's deliberate which I think can be better if you aren't doing anything elaborate.  I'll update the answer with a script that's a bit more abstract and doesn't require you to prime the settings.

Comment: @TommA, We might want to escape some characters such as white spaces, pipe, etc from option values. Those one might be problematic.

Comment: @MS.Kim That's only needed if it was executing `'set statusline='.a:value`.  Since it's using variable assignment, it's not an issue. You can test it with `s:set('statusline', 'pipe | test')` or `s:set('errorformat', '%A testing %m%Z')`

Comment: @TommyA You're right. I thought `let &{option}=a.value` could cause problems as `'set {option}'=a.value` could. But your mention is still valuable for the people (including me) who likely have used only `'set {option}='a.value`.

Answer (score 2):

In [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), I provide a [`lh#on#exit()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/on.vim) function that permits to restore various things to their previous value.

Regarding options, in essence, it just registers (for later) a `exe 'let &opt='.&opt`. I use it this way:

```
let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
      \.restore('&efm')
try
   ... change &efm here ...
   do stuff that may fail
finally
   call cleanup.finalize()
endtry
```

We can register as many restorations as we wish. We can explicitly target a buffer local option with for instance: `l:&efm`. However I'm not aware of any way to say: "fall-back to the global option value".

Note that the `finally` clause is important. If any operation may fail, without it, the option won't be restored to end-user's setting.

I haven't provided a way to restore any possible option -- see @MS.Kim's answer to see how we can obtain their list. Or we could listen the option changed event, or play with the old `c_CTRL-A_HOME` trick (1). 
But, honestly, I really don't see the point. When, locally (in a function), I change option values, I exactly know which options I'll tweak.

Note that I can also:

- restore plugin options (variables) that can be global or buffer local -> `.restore_option(varname)`
- register actions -> `.register(':q')`
- restore buffer local mapping (or undefine them) -> `.restore_buffer_mapping('<c-y>', 'i')`

(1) That I've factorized in lh-vim-lib (as usual) -> `echo lh#command#matching_askvim('option', '')`

```
" Function: lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) {{{3
function! lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) abort
  let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
        \.register('delcom LHAskVimMatchingCompletion')
  try
    exe 'command! -complete='.a:what.' -nargs=* LHAskVimMatchingCompletion :echo "<args>"'
    silent! exe "norm! :LHAskVimMatchingCompletion ".a:lead."\<c-a>\"\<home>let\ cmds=\"\<cr>"
    return split(cmds, ' ')[1:]
  finally
    call cleanup.finalize()
  endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: That looks like a very interesting plugin. I think you make a pretty good point here: `I haven't provided a way to restore any possible option [...]. I don't see the point. When, locally (in a function), I change option values, I exactly know which options I'll tweak.` to be fair I can't remember why I needed that but I agree that it is better to switch only the options you need to change.

Comment: Ah. Since your comment, I've added a way to list all existing options thanks to command line completion -- dirty trick inside.

Comment: (PS: If I ever attend another tuppervim, just ask)

Comment: Ok that's how you recognize a veteran vimmist ;-) I didn't know this old `c_CTRL-A_HOME` trick and I'll need some time to grok your code but thank you very much for providing a solution! (PS I'd gladly meet you in a next tuppervim!)

Comment: That's how we've been proceeding before `get(g:, ` -- which took me some time to discover. It's still useful for non-officially exposed stuff like options, environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If we just limit to 1 aspect and we map it (instead of all user changes as question asks, and  for vimscript instead of map), we can save-set-doStuff-reset easily:

```
let str_zzz="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget libero quis mi gravida sollicitudin sit amet in sem."
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>zzz
\ :let tw_zzz=&tw
\ <bar> :set tw=0<CR><Esc>
\ :execute 'normal! o' . str_zzz<CR>
\ :set tw=&tw_zzz<CR>
```

Explanation. This map pastes a very long string without slicing it every textwidth (`:set tw&`) characters.

- `let tw_zzz=&tw` saves current textwidth
- `set tw=0` anullates it (line width as long as needed)
- `execute 'normal! o' . str_zzz` pastes the [long] string
- `set tw=&tw_zzz` resets the previous textwidth
- `set tw&`  would reset to default (in that filetype), instead to the previous textwidth (as previous command did). Thus, with this option no need of `let tw_zzz=&tw`